# From TFS build workflow, how to open a source control file without downloading it

Tags: tfs, embedded, build-automation, tfsbuild

I'm using TFS 2010 and Team Build 2010 to automate building a C++ project for embedded platform (TI compiler).

I'm want to customize my build version number by reading a file that is under source control.

The problem is that in the default workflow template (the one I've used as a template for my modifications), the build version is defined before "Run On Agent", which is where the source code is downloaded.

Is there a way (from inside a custom code activity) to open a file that is under source control without downloading it?

I already know a workaround - use the drop location root as a sorf of temp folder - to download that file, extract what I need from it, and then delete it. But I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way of doing it.